# jquery countdown in dynamically created html

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

i need a little help using the jquery countdown [keith wood - jquery countdown plugin](http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html)

I am creating several countdowns by retrieving data from mysql database (php ajax call) and putting it into a div:

in php (getdetails.php -> gets $mid and $time from mysql-database):

```
    $mrow="TimeCounter inserted here:"
    $mrow.="<div id=\"RowDiv\"><div id=\"timecount".$mid."\"><script> $('#timecount".$mid."').countdown({until: ".$time."}); </script></div></div>";
    $mrow.="TimeCounter ends here";
```

in JS i set the innerHTML with the data i got:

```
    var url="getDetails.php";
    var what="getTimeData"; 
       console.log("call getTimeData");
    var p1 = $.post(url,{what:what,selId:selValue,conName:"GId"});
        p1.done(function(data){
        console.log("Data -> : "+ data);
        document.getElementById("CounterDiv").innerHTML=data
      });
```

console.log(data) shows me the set html:

```
    <div id="RowDiv" ><div id="timecount2"><script> $('#timecount2').countdown({until: 1454713200}); </script></div></div>
```

I get no errors but i dont see the counter... I do see the surrounding TimeCounter inserted here: TimeCounter ends here on the page. I suppose it is a client / server side issue. Maybe i need to call the function again after setting the innerHTML with the data. But i dont know how.

How can i solve this? Any ideas?

Comment: wait what? you are creating a ajax call to get a page that executes a javascript

Comment: give us your ajax code, have you appended the jquery and the countdown in your page that makes the ajax call?

Comment: i' ll edit the question, one moment please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding an inline script within your HTML element, you can initiate the counter within your callback/success function of `jQuery.post()`. In order to do this, you will have to change your PHP and JS like below:

**PHP**

```
$mrow="TimeCounter inserted here:"
$mrow.="<div id=\"RowDiv\"><div id=\"timecount" . $mid . "\" data-time=\"" . $time . "\"></div></div>";
$mrow.="TimeCounter ends here";
```

**JS**

```
var url = "getDetails.php",
    what = "getTimeData";

$.post(url, {what:what,selId:selValue,conName:"GId"}, function(data){
    $('#CounterDiv').html(data).find('[id^="timecount"]').countdown({until: $(this).data('time')*1});
});
```

---

**UPDATE:**
I don't know the plugin, but the scope of `this` might get changed when `.countdown()` is called. In such a case, you can use `.each()` function of jQuery to pass the element. Here is how you do that:

```
$.post(url, {what:what,selId:selValue,conName:"GId"}, function(data){
    var $counters = $('#CounterDiv').html(data).find('[id^="timecount"]'),
        $el,t;
    $counters.each(function(index,element){
       $el = $(element);
       t = $el.data('time')*1;
       $el.countdown({until: t});
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested the code but the point of my suggestion would be to avoid sending HTML in response and make `getdetails.php` respond with `$mid` and `$time` like:

```
$data = array(
    'mid' => $mid,
    'time' => $time
);
$response = json_encode($data);
```

Your JS code should look something like:

```
var url = "getDetails.php";
var what = "getTimeData";
console.log("call getTimeData");
$.post(url, {what: what, selId: selValue, conName: "GId"}, function (data) {
    console.log("Data -> : " + data);

    var id = 'timecount' + data.mid;
    var row = '<div id="RowDiv"><div id="' + id + '"></div</div>';
    $("#CounterDiv").html(row);
    $('#' + id).countdown({until: data.time});
}, 'json');
```

Comment: thank you! this was something i was trying too. but when i read @ArmanOzak 's answer wanted to do it his way...

Comment: you're welcome :) by the way you should accept his answer